# Is there a convention to call the uninstaller program unins000.exe (on windows)?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I wonder why a lot of programs use the same name for their uninstaller, namely **unins000.exe** . Moreover, I can understand the *unins* part, that is like the *setup* name for installers, it is just English (shortened).

But why is everyone adding the three zeroes at the end?

Comment: Because thats the default name for that file when you use that particular program that generates the installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unins000.exe` is the default name used by [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup).  The `unins` part of the name is hardcoded into the program.

If many programs are being installed into the same folder, the second one would be `unins001.exe` and the third `unins002.exe` and so on.

See: [Change the default name of an Inno-Setup uninstaller to avoid naming conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625533/change-the-default-name-of-an-inno-setup-uninstaller-to-avoid-naming-conflicts).